# Is there a way to do actions as soon as a process is finished processing instead of waiting for all to finish?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, ray

I am using the Ray library to process a bunch of tasks in parallel. The way I am doing this is through adding tasks to be processed, processing them all together, and then updating a queue which limits me to the slowest task at each level. Is there a way to dynamically update the queue every time a task is finished?

Here's some code:

```
    while len(queue) > 0: 
        # add some tasks to be processed from queue
        tasks = [x for x in queue if not some_condition(x)]
        # remove tasks from queue
        queue = [x for x in queue if x not in tasks]
        #call Ray remote function on each node in the tasks
        outputs  = [self.process_nodes.remote(node) for node in tasks]
        # go through outputs, update queue given children and relevant attributes and iterate.
        out = ray.get(outputs)
        do_stuff(out)
```

Regarding the code above, outputs are waiting for all the nodes in the tasks list to finish to that it can move on, I'm wondering if there's a way to get a task from outputs as soon as it finishes, process it, update the queue and process all the remaining nodes in the task?

Comment: maybe if you would use real `queue` then you could use it to send data directly from process to main process (or other process) which would remove task from your pseudo `queue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ray.wait()` to check which tasks are finished and which need to wait longer.

You can run it in loop until you get all results.

```
import time
import ray

@ray.remote
def function(i):
    time.sleep(i)
    return i

print('create tasks')

# create tasks
all_tasks = [function.remote(i) for i in range(4)]

print('wait for results')

# run loop to get all results
while all_tasks:

    # wait for (at least one) finished tasks (and other tasks)
    finished, all_tasks = ray.wait(all_tasks, num_returns=1, timeout=None)
    
    for task in finished:
        result = ray.get(task)
        print('result:', result)
        
    print('len(all_tasks):', len(all_tasks))
```

Result:

```
create tasks
wait for results
result: 0
len(all_tasks): 3
result: 1
len(all_tasks): 2
result: 2
len(all_tasks): 1
result: 3
len(all_tasks): 0
```

If you use `num_returns=2` then it waits for 2 results and you get

```
create tasks
wait for results
result: 0
result: 1
len(all_tasks): 2
result: 2
result: 3
len(all_tasks): 0
```

If you use `time=0.5` then it will wait only 0.5s for result(s) so you may get result like this

```
create tasks
wait for results
result: 0
len(all_tasks): 3
len(all_tasks): 3
len(all_tasks): 3
result: 1
len(all_tasks): 2
len(all_tasks): 2
result: 2
len(all_tasks): 1
len(all_tasks): 1
len(all_tasks): 1
result: 3
len(all_tasks): 0
```

---

Doc: [ray.wait](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/package-ref.html#ray-wait) and [Fetching results](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/walkthrough.html#fetching-results)

Comment: Doesn't calling all_tasks not return anything until the remote functions are all finished running? Or is it the get function that waits for all to return?

Comment: it uses `wait()` to get only tasks which already have results - and later it use `.get()` only with these tasks - so it doesn't check tasks which still don't have results - and it doesn't have to wait for other tasks. It will check other tasks in next loop. It is short example so simply run it to see how it works. It displays first result, next it waits for next results, and later it displays second result and it wait again for next result, etc.